# Mysql group row conflict problem with group command

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql and I got a table with the name users.
Inside the table we got a row group.
When I am trying this command

```
$sql = "SELECT Login,Email,Balance,**Group** FROM users where Email = 'blabla'
```

Unfortunately is not working because the **row group is conflict with the group command.**
What can I do? I can't change the database row as I have view only access.

Comment: Is that the complete question?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It's very simple but the question wasn't full :) You need to see the whole question

Comment: Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as described in Section 9.2, “Schema Object Names”: group is a reserved word see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-G

Comment: I know that is reserved word. So what can I do? I tried to add 'Group' but when it exactract database every row got the word Group and not what is inside database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

group is a reserve word, so you need to use it like `group` - you need to use the char which is under tilda sign in keyboard

```
SELECT Login,Email,Balance,`Group` FROM users where Email = 'blabla'
```

Comment: I already try this but again unfortunately I am getting the text Group in the row and not what is inside my database in Group row

Comment: @Elpidios Take note that there is a difference between ' (single quote) and ` (backtick). You need the latter.

Comment: also I would like to ask you one more thing. When I do echo $row["Group"] my output is like this real/something , real/something2, demo/something , demo/something2. How can I echo only the first four letters (real or demo)?